# Как присвоить картинку из TImageList в контрол TImage?

Tags: delphi, изображения, firemonkey

Есть библиотека изображений лежащих в TImageList. Нужно назначить одну из этих картинок в контрол TImage расположенный на форме.

Сложность в том, что в Firemonkey TImage не имеет свойства ImageList и ImageIndex и использует MultiResBitmap. А TImageList теперь тоже хранит не просто картинки одного размера, а коллекции разных.

Вопрос, как достичь желаемого и использовать картинку из TImageList в контроле TImage?

Comment: Синоним на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить картинку в MultiResBitmap самого TImage:

```
var
  sz: TSize;
  bmpSrc, bmpTgt: TBitmap;

...

// Obtain the bitmap (e.g. from ImageList in data-module)
sz := TSize.Create(MaxInt, MaxInt); // Pick best size
DataModule1.ImageList1.BestSize(3, sz);
bmpSrc := DataModule1.ImageList1.Bitmap(sz, 3);

// Assign to Image1, to desired scale
bmpTgt := Image1.MultiResBitmap.Bitmaps[1.0];
bmpTgt.SetSize(bmpSrc.Size);
bmpTgt.Assign(bmpSrc);
```